# How can I loop through this pandas dataframe faster?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this loop that iterates over a dataframe and creates a cumulative value. I have around 450k rows in my dataframe and it takes in excess of 30 minutes to complete.

Here is the head of my dataframe:

```
timestamp  open   high  low     close   volume  vol_thrs    flg

1970-01-01 09:30:59 136.01  136.08  135.94  136.030 5379100 0.0 0.0
1970-01-01 09:31:59 136.03  136.16  136.01  136.139 759900  0.0 0.0
1970-01-01 09:32:59 136.15  136.18  136.10  136.180 609000  0.0 0.0
1970-01-01 09:33:59 136.18  136.18  136.07  136.100 510900  0.0 0.0
1970-01-01 09:34:59 136.11  136.15  136.05  136.110 306400  0.0 0.0
```

The timestamp column is the index.

Any thoughts on how I make this quicker?

```
for (i, (idx, row)) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if i == 0:
        tmp_cum = df.loc[idx, 'volume']
    else:
        tmp_cum = tmp_cum + df.loc[idx, 'volume']

    if tmp_cum >= df.loc[idx, 'vol_thrs']:
        tmp_cum = 0
        df.loc[idx, 'flg'] = 1
```

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of data so we can understand what this calculation is doing?

Comment: I can't really without revealing too much about what I'm doing. :-/

Comment: OK. I mean you don't have to share your real data, your data can be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` for all intents, we just need something we can run.

Comment: I've edited the post with a sample dataframe. Of course the real one has over 450k rows.

Comment: It looks like you only care about the 'volume' column, and the ordering (since you are looping over rows in order of index). Can you instead just do your iteration over a numpy array of volumes? e.g. vol_array = df.volume.values, then do your iteration over vol_array? Should be orders of magnitude faster than repeatedly searching for and grabbing individual rows of the df.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `df.at` instead of `df.loc`, as so:

```
for (i, (idx, row)) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
if i == 0:
    tmp_cum = df.at[idx, 'volume']
else:
    tmp_cum = tmp_cum + df.at[idx, 'volume']

if tmp_cum >= df.at[idx, 'vol_thrs']:
    tmp_cum = 0
    df.at[idx, 'flg'] = 1
```

`df.at` should theoretically perform better. `df.at` is better if you're accessing a single data value, which is the case in your function. `df.loc` will let you do slicing, but `df.at` won't.

Comment: Wow! Down from 37 minutes to 13 seconds :) Thanks